# [C#][SqlConnection] SqlException related to connection to Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am working in C# and deal with SQL Server using a `SqlConnection`. For some reason, I just keep alive one `SqlConnection` (I don't close it after invoke `SqlCommand`, keep it alive).

In next time invoke `SqlCommand`, it can have two type of `SqlException`.

1. One is some exception related to server causes the connection will be lost (Server Down, Internet down or Database takes offline, Database dropped).
2. The remain is exception related to query execution like (SQL query is incorrect, parameters is missing or duplicate primary key, etc...), errors not related to the connection (connection is well).

I need to catch the first exception (connection down error) to warning to user, and ignore the retain.

But currently, It's has many error codes related connection down error (4406, 223,...) I don't sure that I missed any code.

Would you please help me cover case of the `SqlConnection` down issue?

[image]

Comment: Could you paste your code here for us to look at?

Comment: Best practice is to open/close a connection as needed, they are pooled by the framework so its cheaper to do than you think.  For a definitive test try checking the connections .State property or execute a know good statement `select 1` etc & see if it succeeds.

Comment: `By some reason, I just keep alive one SqlConnection` don't do this

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot?

Comment: @ChrisL, I have posted it as your request. As you see, I have an infinite loop thread to an Command Queue, just take queue and run.

Comment: Screenshot instead of code and `while(true)`? Really?

Comment: @MichaelRandall No, I cannot close it, one is it by customer request, and one is I need to save time to each milisecond, so that, Connection is keep alive

Comment: There's too much going on that we have no information about. Please see [mcve] and post the relevant code sections. As code. Not as screenshot.

Comment: A good start would be to wrap your `SqlConnection` in a `using ()` statement - there's a reason it was designed this way.

Comment: are you trying to handle a generic exception with an IF statement ? if yes, then try{}catch{} is there for that reason, use it instead of if statetment, and also check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx get the exception by its number.